# Centering strings with printf()

Tags: c, printf

By default, `printf()` seems to align strings to the right.

```
printf("%10s %20s %20s\n", "col1", "col2", "col3");
/*       col1                 col2                 col3 */
```

I can also align text to the left like this:

```
printf("%-10s %-20s %-20s", "col1", "col2", "col3");
```

Is there a quick way to center text? Or do I have to write a function that turns a string like `test` into `(space)(space)test(space)(space)` if the text width for that column is 8?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

printf by itself can't do the trick, but you could play with the "indirect" width, which specifies the width by reading it from an argument. Lets' try this (ok, not perfect)

```
void f(char *s)
{
        printf("---%*s%*s---\n",10+strlen(s)/2,s,10-strlen(s)/2,"");
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        f("uno");
        f("quattro");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tested this in some C++ code I wrote to create table, and it was truncating valid text, and I had to figure out why. I've provided an alternative answer based on how I resolved it.

Comment: Correct, indeed I warned that the solution is "not perfect", due to hard coded constants it contains. My goal was just to give a hint, your solution completes the idea.

Comment: The `*` expects an `int`, `strlen()` will return `size_t`. This function causes UB when `SIZE_MAX>INT_MAX`. Possible solution: Change it to `(int) ((10+strlen(s)/2)&INT_MAX)`

Comment: Correct. In most cases casting strlen directly to int is enough. It's unlikely that a string that was meant to be centered exceeds INT_MAX in length.

Answer (score 14):

@GiuseppeGuerrini's was helpful, by suggesting how to use print format specifiers and dividing the whitespace. Unfortunately, it can truncate text.

The following solves the problem of truncation (assuming the field specified  is actually large enough to hold the text).

```
void centerText(char *text, int fieldWidth) {
    int padlen = (fieldWidth - strlen(text)) / 2;
    printf("%*s%s%*s\n", padLen, "", text, padlen, "");
}
```

Comment: note that the resulting total width will be different depending on if `fieldWidth - strlen(text)` is even or odd

Comment: added a modified version that always prints `fieldWidth` characters (e.g. for use in tables etc.)

Comment: The behavior is implementations defined when the result of `(fieldWidth - strlen(text)) / 2;` is out of the range of an `int`. Which can be the case when `SIZE_MAX>INT_MAX` and `strlen(text)>fieldWidth`, causing `(fieldWidth - strlen(text)) == SIZE_MAX-(strlen(text)-fieldWidth-1)`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 
 Reminds me of the old adage "Just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you should."

Answer (score 2):

There is no `printf()` format specifier to centre text.

You will need to write your own function or locate a library which provides the functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: Your opportunity to go the extra 9 yards to provide a solution, eh?

Answer (score 2):

You may try write own function for this problem.

```
/**
 * Returns a sting "str" centered in string of a length width "new_length".
 * Padding is done using the specified fill character "placeholder".
 */
char *
str_center(char str[], unsigned int new_length, char placeholder)
{
    size_t str_length = strlen(str);

    // if a new length is less or equal length of the original string, returns the original string
    if (new_length <= str_length)
        return str;

    char *buffer;
    unsigned int i, total_rest_length;

    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * new_length);

    // length of a wrapper of the original string
    total_rest_length = new_length - str_length;

    // write a prefix to buffer
    i = 0;
    while (i < (total_rest_length / 2)) {
        buffer[i] = placeholder;
        ++i;
    }
    buffer[i + 1] = '\0';

    // write the original string
    strcat(buffer, str);

    // write a postfix to the buffer
    i += str_length;
    while (i < new_length) {
        buffer[i] = placeholder;
        ++i;
    }
    buffer[i + 1] = '\0';

    return buffer;
}
```

**Results:**

```
puts(str_center("A", 0, '-')); // A
puts(str_center("A", 1, '-')); // A
puts(str_center("A", 10, '-')); // ----A-----
puts(str_center("text", 10, '*')); // ***text***
puts(str_center("The C programming language", 26, '!')); // The C programming language
puts(str_center("The C programming language", 27, '!')); // The C programming language!
puts(str_center("The C programming language", 28, '!')); // !The C programming language!
puts(str_center("The C programming language", 29, '!')); // !The C programming language!!
puts(str_center("The C programming language", 30, '!')); // !!The C programming language!!
puts(str_center("The C programming language", 31, '!')); // !!The C programming language!!!
```

Comment: Cool that it is c/stdlib only implementation for the standpoint of educating about C but otherwise at least replace the prefix/postfix loops with `memcpy()` or `bcopy()`

Comment: And replace malloc with alloca.. ewww

Comment: alloca wouldn't work in this instance, as the string being returned is in that memory - you don't want it be free'd at the point of the 'str_center' returns! But as Martin points out, as written this leaks memory.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions, the first is similar to the above, by placing macros in printf, and the second is a custom macro, which calculates the length of the formatted string in advance through snprintf, and then calls the printf function to output.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEFT(str, w) \
    ({int m = w + strlen(str); m % 2 ? (m + 1) / 2 : m / 2;})

#define RIGHT(str, w) \
({ int m = w - strlen(str); m % 2 ? (m - 1) / 2 : m / 2; })

#define STR_CENTER(str, width) \
    LEFT(str, width), str, RIGHT(str, width), ""

#define PRINTF_CENTER(width, start, fmt, end, ...) ({ \
    int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, __VA_ARGS__);     \
    int m = width - n;                               \
    int left = m % 2 ? (m + 1) / 2 : m / 2;          \
    int right = m % 2 ? (m - 1) / 2 : m / 2;         \
    printf(start "%*s" fmt "%*s" end, left, "",      \
           __VA_ARGS__, right, "");                  \
})

#define MYFORMAT_CENTER(width, fmt, ...)  \
    PRINTF_CENTER(40, "[", fmt  , "]\n", __VA_ARGS__)

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("%*s%*s\n\n", STR_CENTER("--- Hello World ---", 40));
    printf("[%*s%*s]\n", STR_CENTER("I am okay today", 40));
    
    MYFORMAT_CENTER(40, "%d, e is %f", 1, 2.71828);
    MYFORMAT_CENTER(40, "%d, pi is %f", 2, 3.1415926);
    MYFORMAT_CENTER(40, "%s %d.", "This is such a long string that it exceeds the given size:", 40);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
           --- Hello World ---

[             I am okay today            ]
[            1, e is 2.718280            ]
[            2, pi is 3.141593           ]
[           This is such a long string that it exceeds the given size: 40.           ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ill drop my 2 cents after dealing with similar issue of trying to center a table headers in a row with printf.

The following macros will need to be printed before/after the text and will align regardless of the length of the text itself.
Notice that if we have odd length strings, we will not align as should(because the normal devision will result in missing space).
Therefor a round up is needed, and I think this is the elegant way to solve that issue:

```
#define CALC_CENTER_POSITION_PREV(WIDTH, STR) (((WIDTH + ((int)strlen(STR))) % 2) \
       ? ((WIDTH + ((int)strlen(STR)) + 1)/2) : ((WIDTH + ((int)strlen(STR)))/2))
#define CALC_CENTER_POSITION_POST(WIDTH, STR) (((WIDTH - ((int)strlen(STR))) % 2) \
       ? ((WIDTH - ((int)strlen(STR)) - 1)/2) : ((WIDTH - ((int)strlen(STR)))/2))
```

Usage example:

```
printf("%*s%*s" , CALC_CENTER_POSITION_PREV(MY_COLUMN_WIDTH, "Header")
                , "Header"
                , CALC_CENTER_POSITION_POST(MY_COLUMN_WIDTH, "Header"), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will either have to write your own function that returns "  test  " etc, e.g.

```
printf("%s %s %s", center("col1", 10), center("col2", 20), center("col3", 20));
```

Or you have a center_print function, something like the following:

```
void center_print(const char *s, int width)
{
        int length = strlen(s);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<=(width-length)/2; i++) {
                fputs(" ", stdout);
        }
        fputs(s, stdout);
        i += length;
        for (; i<=width; i++) {
                fputs(" ", stdout);
        }
}
```

Comment: The first suggestion: How can this be impl'd without leaking memory?

Comment: If you preallocate some buffers based on some criteria that does not seem unreasonable (like for instance no more than 20 arguments will be centred for one printf, and none of the centred results will be longer than 200 bytes), you could let the center function just rotate buffers on each invocation.

Answer (score 0):

A more compact version of PADYMKO's function above (which still leaks memory):

```
char *str_center(char str[], unsigned int new_length, char placeholder)
{
    size_t str_length = strlen(str);
    char *buffer;
    /*------------------------------------------------------------------
     * If a new length is less or equal length of the original string, 
     * returns the original string 
     *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    if (new_length <= str_length)
    {
        return(str);
    }
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (new_length + 1));
    memset(buffer, placeholder, new_length);
    buffer[new_length] = '\0';
    bcopy(str, buffer + (( new_length - str_length) / 2), str_length);
    return(buffer);
}
```

This sets the whole of newly allocated buffer to the padding character, null terminates that, and then drops the string to be centred into the middle of the buffer - no loops, or keeping track of where to copy to..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use a `printf()` format string for that and you accept to be limited to the GNU clib, you can extend `printf()` with your own conversion specifier for centering a string with. Add the conversion specifier with `register_printf_function()`.
See here for the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html
The other answers already provide you with a solution on how to manually print a string in the center, which you still need when using your own conversion specifier.

Answer (score -2):

You can use either of the following two options:

```
char name[] = "Name1";

//Option One
printf("%*s", 40+strlen(name)/2, name, 40-strlen(name)/2, "");
puts("");//skip one line
```

```
//Option two
printf("%*s", 40+strlen("Name2")/2, "Name2", 40-strlen("Name2")/2, "");
```

The output is:

Name1(center)
Name2(center)

Comment: First of all, this looks like a ripoff of Giuseppe's answer, and, secondly, you have more printf() arguments than you have format specifiers to accommodate them. Did you even test this?