# formatting bash in linux - printf align middle

Tags: bash, printf

This line of code:

```
printf 'ddd %-22s dddd \n' "eeeeeee"
```

Aligns to the left.

What could I use to align it to centre like this:

```
ddd      eeeeeee      dddd
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how can I change the code so it would align eeeeeee in the middle?

Comment: it's not already in the middle? ie. eeeeee is between ddd and ddd, so, in the middle, isn't?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering strings with printf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461667/centering-strings-with-printf)

Comment: It is in the middle because I put it there , not the actual code :)    so it seems to me I will write my own function, as says in duplicate  , thanks

Comment: @kojiro That one is for C, this one is for Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit tricky ... but what about this? ;)

```
STR="eeeeeee"; printf 'ddd %11s%-11s dddd \n' `echo $STR | cut -c 1-$((${#STR}/2))` `echo $STR | cut -c $((${#STR}/2+1))-${#STR}`
```

Comment: It is pretty good, but the gap between `eeeeeee      dddd` is widening if I change `%11s%-11s` to  `%22s%-22s`. I would like to be constant.

Comment: I would like to add more characters in `dddd` so it wold be `ddd      eeeeeee      dddd` or 
`ddddd      eeeeeee      dddddd` after widening, with same empty space between `eeeeeee      dddddd`

Comment: Hi andrej, I do not understand why you change to %22s%-22s. The %11s%-11s of the solution already sums 22 spaces (left part of STR is right aligned in 11 spaces, and right part of STR is left aligned in 11 spaces).

Answer (score 2):

printf not support it, but easy to implement it:

```
D="12"    # input string
BS=10     # buffer size
L=$(((BS-${#D})/2))
[ $L -lt 0 ] && L=0
printf "start %${L}s%s%${L}s end\n" "" $D ""
```

Comment: It is pretty good, but the gap between `eeeeeee      dddd` is widening if I increase BS. I would like to be constant.

Comment: I would like to add more characters in `dddd` so it wold be `ddd      eeeeeee      dddd` or 
`ddddd      eeeeeee      dddddd` after widening, with same empty space between `eeeeeee      dddddd`

Answer (score -1):

Just add some tabs around it?

```
printf "ddd\t\teeeeee\t\tddd"
```