# Constructing pascal's triangle (acute angled) with C

Tags: c, pascals-triangle

I'm quite new to programming and just learned the basics of C.I was trying to build the pascal's triangle with C. But can't make it acute angled.

This is what I've done.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n,s=1;
    do
    {
        printf("give the value of n: \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    while(n<0);
    for (int i=0; i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("1  ");
        for (int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            s=s*(i-j+1)/(j);
                printf("%d  ",s);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}
```

this gives a right angled triangle, like

```
                                        1
                                        1 1
                                        1 2 1
                                        1 3 3 1 
                                        1 4 6 4 1
```

but how to make it an acute angled one? like

```
                                                     1
                                                    1 1
                                                   1 2 1 
                                                  1 3 3 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Calculate the number of spaces needed at the beginning of each line.

Comment: When you created this question, what did you do to make the look you want? Can you do that in C?

Comment: You have to know how long the longest line will be — the numbers get quite large quite quickly — and then design your printing to space things appropriately.  The good news is that the numbers are symmetric.

Comment: Your indentation is very much improveable. Note thats consistent indentatsion is extremely useful, not to say required, when dealing with non-trivial loop structures.

Comment: I recommend to provide the actual output of your program here. The one you show will make it harder for you to notice what needs to be done. Same for the desired output.

Comment: By the way, the cryptical commenting (not only by me) is more or less according to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Yunnosch I tried to put a for loop in c to make the look, but I can't think any possible ways as I haven't put any upper bound to n . Now I'm trying to understand the answers to my question, I'm just a beginner in programing:)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem that might arise to get a nice printout is that the size of the number strings varies. Note that e.g. first two-digit number already appears at 6<sup>th</sup> row, first three-digit number at 10<sup>th</sup>. You won't get a clean triangle if you don't take that into account:

```
          1
         1 1
       1 121 1
    1 1331 1331 1
1 14641 14641 14641 1
```

Just for illustration, of course the effect is not as drastic with real values and occurs later, still it exists.

So for a clean triangle you need to reserve boxes for the values of the triangle, blocks of output all of the same size where you centre the individual values within and pad the rest with spaces (visualised by periods below):

```
            ..1..
         ..1.. ..1..
      ..1.. .121. ..1..
   ..1.. .1331 .1331 ..1..
..1.. 14641 14641 14641 ..1..
```

Question now is how large these boxes need to be; luckily there's a closed formula for each position in the triangle, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Formula), and the largest value is always the one in the middle of the last row (or any one of the two middle values, if there's an even number of values), so for *`m`* lines to print you use *`m-1`* for *`n`* and *`m/2`* for *`k`*, thus:

```
unsigned int num = 1; den = 1;
for(unsigned int n = m - 1, k = 1, m2 = m / 2; k <= m2; ++k, --n)
{
    num *= n;
    den *= k;
}
unsigned int max = num/den;
```

Now you can count the number of digits by simply dividing by 10 until reaching zero, et voilà, this is your box size. Centering the number within is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461667/centering-strings-with-printf), so I won't cover it in this answer.

Then the rest is rather simple: You need indentation blocks all of the same number of spaces, the initial line is indented by *`m-1`* of such blocks and each subsequent one uses one less until the last line finally is not indented any more at all (i.e. by zero blocks).

Size of the indentation blocks? I experimented a little and discovered that the triangle gets a cleaner look if you use an odd value box size (so if number of digits is even, increment block size by one), say this is *`b`*. Then indentation blocks should consist of *`(b+1)/2`* spaces, assuming you separate the value boxes by one single space.

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` returns the number of characters printed. You could save all the lines as strings and then print them centered using the length of the last line. But what the heck, just compute the triangle twice. Then nothing advanced like `malloc()` would be needed.

Do it once just to get the length of the last line (you can use `snprintf()` into a zero-length buffer to get that length), and then compute it again to print out the lines centered. For each line you can first use `snprintf()` to get the length, and then `printf()` with a `%*s` in the format and `n, "",`  in the arguments to precede it with `n` spaces. Ok, really three times, since you'll need to compute the length of each line again. Though you could save the lengths in a variable length array, which C permits.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my implementation of pascal's triangle or use it as a reference.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
     int rows,k=1,m,i,j;
     printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
     scanf("%d",&rows);
     for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
         for(m=1;m<=rows-i;m++){
             printf("  "); //added space here for formatting
         }
         for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
             if(j==0 || i==0){
                k=1;
             }
             else{
                k=k*(i-j+1)/j;
                printf("%4d",k);
         }
         printf("\n");
     }
}
```

You will get the output as this:

```
Enter the number of rows: 4
           1
         1   1
       1   2   1
    1    3   3   1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It didn't work properly, I just manipulated it a little bit then it worked. Though the number of digits in nCr when n gets larger matters, but still it looks an acute angle one, not very symmetrical.